Fresh installs of Ubuntu and multiverse
Let's say I install Ubuntu and decide to download all the extended additional software, drivers, and codecs straight from the OS installation wizard. Does any of the additional software from a clean install of the OS use multiverse? Now I know how to disable downloading from multiverse AFTER Ubuntu is installed, and I know that doing the most basic installation settings won't take anything from multiverse.
But I want to know if any fresh installs of Ubuntu would ever take anything from multiverse, depending on what settings you choose.
Edit: The reason I would like to avoid the multiverse repository is that there is software there that may have questionable legality. It might seem like a rather heavy-handed way, but the reasoning is this: if I disable that repository, then regular system installs, updates, etc., aren't going to plant something potentially illegal unintentionally.
It seems strange, but realizing that Linux Mint installs libdvdcss2 by default really rubbed me the wrong way.

If you disable ANY of your software sources (multiverse is one), you will no longer receive software updates from that source. No bug fixes, no security uppdates, no snaps, nothing. Are you sure that is what you want? Your fear of the multiverse repository seems nonsensical. Could you [edit] your Question  to explain?

Yeah, that's sounds like what I want. See the edits for why. No, I don't think I'm going to get in trouble. It's just that it's genuinely important to me to make sure I'm working with legal software and libraries.

A stock install of Ubuntu, using the default settings, will use packages only from the main pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. Not universe nor multiverse.
Some additional drivers, codecs, etc. may come from multiverse. But you must so elect. The default settings are main only.
If in doubt, stick with the default settings during install. You can always easily change or add different sources and packages later.

multiverse software does not meet Ubuntu standards for open source and/or compatible licensing to be in universe, but multiverse software MUST still be licensed for free redistribution. multiverse has NEVER been a swamp of piracy or malware. It is patrolled by the community.

If you discover pirated software or malware in any Ubuntu repository, file a bug report and include the Ubuntu Security Team.

multiverse software is generally ineligible for unattended upgrades, as the Ubuntu Security Team's focus is on main (everybody) and some universe (Pro customers) packages. The stock settings for unattended upgrades omit multiverse entirely.


